# C# How can I create a panel according the location of the previous panel created from code?

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

Example on one picture down. I want to create a panel foreach person in my database, and each one contains information about that person. My doubt isn't how to make it, it's how to add one according the location of the previous one? Like an online shopping cart for instance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be create a `FlowLayoutPanel` and add you Items to it, the flowlayout panel will take care of thier positioning. just set its autoscroll:

```
flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
```

and flow direction:

```
flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection=FlowDirection.TopDown;
```

You can google about flowlayout panel and find many examples, [this is one of them](https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/405/flowlayoutpanel-control-in-c-sharp-dot-net).

The second option would be adding panels below each other and adding a `VertialScrollBar` to the form with dock (left or right) and you should then hanlde the scrolling yourself.

As for adding each panel below the previous (not needed in the first way as flowlayoutpanel will take care of it)

Assuming your panels are in an array named `panels`

```
for(int i=0;i<panels.Length;i++)
{
    int top = i == 0 ? 0 : panels[i - 1].Top + panels[i - 1].Width; //this line not needed in flowlayout panel
    panels[i].Location = new Point(0, top);//this line not needed in flowlayout panel
    Parent.Controls.Add(panels[i]); //parent can be your form, a panel, ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, first I would create an `UserControl` to represent an item, and to list it, I would use a `Panel` with `AutoScroll` and a `TableLayoutPanel` inside it (with AutoSize set to true, with 1 column and 1 row).

Like this you only need to add Controls (wich you will use the `UserControl` you created) to the `TableLayoutPanel`.